# Searching 10 fields

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have ten fields that needs to be searched..It consists of 10 text-boxes, each text box has its own assigned column in the database that's needed to be searched..It has a single search button. My problem is that i have no control which of these boxes will be filled by the user..Therefore I need to dynamically check if the fields are empty or not..attached herewith is my sample code..I was hoping that you guys can give me a much simpler approach..

Textboxes: 
    1. Registration Date
    2. Link Code
    3. Bldg Code
    4. Bldg Desc
    5. Street Desc
    6. Village Desc
    7. Area Desc
    8. District Desc
    9. State Desc
    10. Country Desc

In the sample code below under Function Items:
    Parameter actDate = textbox Registration Date
    Parameter linkCode = textbox Link Code
    Parameter bldgCode = textbox Bldg Code
    parameter bldgDesc = textbox Bldg Desc

So far, ive only added 4 textbox in my code..I stopped because I was wondering if there is a much simpler way to do this.. thanks.

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    accountDt = New DataTable
    accountDt = Items(txtActDate.Text, txtLinkCode.Text, txtBldgCode.Text, txtBldgDesc.Text, "select * from ac_account", "ACTIVATION_DATE_D")
    LoadData(btnCheckAll, btnUnCheckAll, btnAccountWrite, btnAccountFirst, btnAccountPrevious, btnAccountNext, btnAccountLast, _
             lblAccountPage, lstAccount, "ACCOUNT_NAME_V", "ACTIVATION_DATE_D", "ACTIVATED_BY_N", accountDt, "ACSP_AccountLoad", _
             "ACTIVATION_DATE_D", btnMatrix)
    txtActDate.Text = ""
    txtLinkCode.Text = ""
    txtBldgCode.Text = ""
    txtBldgDesc.Text = ""
```

End Sub

```
Public Function Items(ByVal actDate As String, ByVal linkCode As String, ByVal bldgCode As String, ByVal bldgDesc As String, ByVal query As String, _
                     ByVal actRegDate As String) As DataTable
    Try
        If actDate <> "" And linkCode <> "" And bldgCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And linkCode <> "" And bldgCode <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And linkCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And bldgCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf linkCode <> "" And bldgCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And linkCode <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And bldgCode <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf linkCode <> "" And bldgCode <> "" Then
            query = query & " where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "'"
        ElseIf linkCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf bldgCode <> "" And bldgDesc <> "" Then
            query = query & " where BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "' and BUILDING_DESC_V = '" & bldgDesc & "'"
        ElseIf actDate <> "" Then
            query = query & " where convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "'"
        ElseIf linkCode <> "" Then
            query = query & " where ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" & linkCode & "'"
        ElseIf bldgCode.ToLower <> "" Then
            query = query & " where BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "'"
        ElseIf bldgDesc.ToLower <> "" Then
            query = query & " where BUILDING_DESC_V LIKE '" & bldgDesc & "%" & "'"
        End If
        conn.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sqlDt = New DataTable
        sqlDa = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    Return sqlDt
End Function
```

Comment: I've came across this same issue. I don't think there's a good work around for it.  However, considering your code you could clean it up by removing appending the where to the query string every line. That way if you want to use two columns to narrow the search you would just need to change the elseifs to ifs.

Comment: My solution below implements a version of what you recommend in terms of appending the clauses.

Comment: You need to think seriously about using parameters to avoid sql injection attacks...before Bobby Tables comes knocking. http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 1):

We do this (unfortunately, this is c#, but the .NET calls translate):

```
List<String> phrases = new List<String>();
if (actDate != "") phrases.Add("convert(varchar(10),actRegDate,101) = '" + actDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";
if (linkCode != "") phrases.Add"(ACCOUNT_LINK_CODE_N = '" + linkCode + "'");
```

Continue adding phrases to the `List`. When you are finished, you can create the `WHERE` clause with `String.Join`:

String whereClause = String.Join(" AND ", phrases);

Which you can then use in you SQL.

Once caveat: I would **strongly suggest** using parameters instead of concatenating the values directly into the phrase. When I have done this in the past, I just added all of the parameters to the `SqlCommand` whether they were in the actual query or not.

However, if LINQ2SQL is an option, it will do all of these things for you, including the query composition.

Comment: OK. Now it is. It's even a different answer.

Comment: +1; Using the List of strings is a good approach because it is clean, readable, and easily changed. The suggestion to use parameters should be changed to "strongly recommended".

Answer (score -1):

For each non-empty search box you should be adding another condition to the WHERE. If you don't want to track if a condition was added already add 1=1 to start. One IF per search box.

```
query = query & "WHERE 1=1 "
IF actDate <> "" THEN 
  query = query & " AND convert(varchar(10)," & actRegDate & ",101) = '" & actDate & "'"
END IF
IF bldgCode <> "" THEN 
   query = query & " and BUILDING_CODE_V = '" & bldgCode & "'"
END IF
```

With additional IF lines for each search box.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to provide an answer that is prone to sql injection attacks.